# Unable to download app from Google play. Android app is supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm facing the strange error with AndroidManifest, obviously, somehting isn't right with my AndroidManifest since Google reject device support.

Here is an example of fully merged AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:versionCode="10009" android:versionName="1.0.9" 
   package="" platformBuildVersionCode="25" 
     platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1" />
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/civitavecchia_app_icon" android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.AppRelease" android:allowBackup="false" android:largeHeap="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/civitavecchia_app_icon">
    <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.discoveredPOIs.DiscoveredPOIsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.bestHunters.BestHuntersActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.gallery.GalleryActivity" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.introduction.IntroductionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.maps.MapsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.other.LeisureActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.other.PracticalInfoActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.pois.POIsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.ar.AugmentedRealityActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.pois.POIDetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.profile.MyDetailsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.rulesAndRegistration.RulesAndRegistrationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.ScavengerHuntDetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.ScavengerHuntMapActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.ScavengerHuntResultsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.ScavengerHuntResultsDetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.ScavengerHuntsHomeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.ScavengerHuntQuestionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.scavengerHunt.CongratulationsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.other.InfoActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.settings.SettingsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="hr.sil.civitavecchia.activities.settings.LanguagesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="locale" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="XXXXXXXX" />
    <receiver android:name="hr.sil.android.ble.scanner.waker.WakeUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:label="restartService" android:name="hr.sil.android.ble.scanner.waker.RestartService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:isolatedProcess="false" />
    <receiver android:name="hr.sil.android.bgsync.receiver.BackgroundAlarmReceiver" />
    <service android:name="hr.sil.android.bgsync.service.BackgroundService" />
    <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

I successfully published apk in beta release and production also, however, I didn't have a luck to download the app. Is there some kind of manifest analyzer which will point out mistakes in XML file. iOS rejects you and tell you the reason, but on Play store, the only option is to exclude some permissions and include one permission per release to identify where the problem is, that is hard if you have libraries.

Comment: This might also a factor `android:required="true"`

Comment: What do you mean, that google play doesn't accept default android:required tag, or ?

Comment: No I mean Google Play will hide the apps from those devices that did not meet the requirements. I see that you have so many permission needed and I doubt that if there is a device that satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: @stef It accepts but it actually filters out devices without GPS, or compass, or gyroscope, etc Also by default the required field is true if not declared, the best practice would be to add the required field only when you want to make a feature not required.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that but I was not expecting 0 supported devices  :) .. I guess lots of devices have those sensors which I require by app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />
```

The android.hardware.camera is more than enough.

If you look into the camera basic sample you can see they declare only the android.hardware.camera feature.

Google Camera sample
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Dude this was the cause.. thank you very much. Link me if you ever visit Croatia ;) ... cheers.